# RabbitMQ fail-safe feature - automatic requeue at timeout

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I am implementing some APIs that consume messages from an AMQP queue (specifically RabbitMQ). Those APIs rely on other APIs to work so there is the possibility for them to fail during the message manipulation/handling.

I wanted to make the message handling fail-safe: if the API fails in *any* way I'd like the message to be requeued automatically so I can be sure that it will be processed at least 1 time (doesn't matter when).

Is there an option to implement a fail-safe feature in RabbitMQ so that if the message is not acknowledged in **n** number of seconds it gets automatically requed and automatically consumed again?

I know that if the client does not ACK the message and disconnects the message is sent again when it reconnects, but that is not my case (or better said, this represents a very small amount of failure cases) since the client is always online but can fail in handling the message.
I also know that this fail-safe can be implemented in my code but I would have to handle a huge number of exceptions manually so it would be great to have it message server-side.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such mechanism. Forcing the connection closed (call `resetConnection()` on the `CachingConnectionFactory`) would do what you want, but your consumer will continue to process.